# SQL Contar registros que empiecen por xxx

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Quiero contar los registros de la columna 1 que empiecen por 123, necesito contar multiples veces, con distintos valores (123, 657, 897, ...) los valores los tengo en la columna 2

```
 - column1 | column2
 - 1234567 | 123
 - 5489186 | 135
 - 1238756 | 548

SELECT column1, LEFT(column1,3) AS prefijo, column2 COUNT(LEFT(column1 = 123))
FROM DDBB.table
```

Comment: ¿La columna es numérica o alfanumérica?

Comment: varchar(50) aunque solo tiene registros numericos

Comment: ¿Qué significa *necesito contar multiples veces, con distintos valores*? ¿Significa que quieres un conteo aparte por ciertos valores o que quieres un conteo global basado en varios valores? Esa afirmación hace tu pregunta totalmente **confusa**. ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de los resultados esperados?

Comment: Quiero contar cuantes veces han llamado de una ciudad, en la columna 1 estan todas las llamadas que se han hecho , y en la columna 2 los prefijos de las ciudades. En pocas palabras quiero saber, cuantes veces han llamado de Madrid, pero no solo quiero saber las de Madrid, tambien las de Sevilla, Bilbao, etc...

Comment: Perdona que insista, pero todavía no queda claro... ¿Qué representa la columna1, números de teléfono? ¿Esos números corresponden a un prefijo a partir del cual se podría determinar la ciudad? ¿Qué representa la columna2? Es un dato importante, porque si desde la columna1 se puede determinar la ciudad en base al prefijo puedes usar esa columna para saber cuántas llamadas hay de una ciudad X, sin tener que *crear* una segunda columna con datos que ya tienes. Por otra parte, todavía no queda clara la afirmación *necesito contar multiples veces, con distintos valores*.

Comment: @A.Cedano La columna 1 es varchar(50), solo almacena números de telefonos(976265879), en la 2 tengo los prefijos de las ciudades (976), solo me es importante la columna 1 ya que tengo que contar los registros de llamadas, pero separandolo por ciudades, es una consulta para una web php, en la que saldra una tabla con las ciudades y el numero de veces que han llamado desde esas ciudades. Y a lo de contar multiples veces me refiero a lo de contar las de Madrid, las de Sevilla, las de Bilbao, etc...

Comment: Si quieres contar las de varios sitios como tu dices, _Agrupando_ de las distintas zonas deberás usar un Group By

Comment: @Gabriela, si la columna 2 tiene el prefijo de la ciudad, los datos que mostraste son inconsistentes. El número 1238756 no tiene prefijo 548. Además esa estructura es redundante. A lo mejor quieres decir que la columna 2 tiene el prefijo y la columna 1 tiene el número **sin prefijo**?

Comment: Son dos columnas de tablas diferentes, he puesto un ejemplo de ellas ya filtradas y buscadas. En la columna 1 esta el numero entero con prefijo, y en la 2 solo el prefijo. Es una base de datos ya creada

Comment: Pero sigo sin entender ¿por qué si en la columna 2 tienes el prefijo, tienes que usar la columna1?

Comment: En la columna 1 estan almacenadas miles y miles de miles de numeros de llamadas y estan repetidos los numeros, puede haber 10 con el prefijo 975, pero son numeros distintos (976232323, 975696969), tengo que contar las llamadas, las veces que ha llado un numero empezando con 975. La columna 2 es irrelevante, pero esta de "apoyo".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supongamos que tu tabla tiene los datos

```
column1  | column2
 ------------------
 '123123' | '123'
 '123456' | '231'
 '123321' | '312'
 '123654' | '321'
 '456123' | '213'
 '456654' | '132'
 '456456' | '456'
 '789123' | '564'
 '789321' | '645'
```

Si quieres saber cuántos valores de la columna2 comparten los primeros 3 caracteres en la columna 1:

```
select left(column1,3) prefijo, 
       count(*) cantidad 
from mitabla
group by left(column1,3);
```

Esto entrega:

```
prefijo | cantidad
------------------
  123   |   4
  456   |   3
  789   |   2
```

[Te dejo un fiddle funcionando](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cfc83/6)

Comment: Gracias a todos por la ayuda, pero en especial a @amenadiel, me has dado la solución, despues de 7 intentos de diferentes formas. Era más sencillo de como me lo estaba planteando yo xD

Answer (score 2):

Basándome en los comentarios anteriores, creo que lo que necesitas es algo así --> [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a55506/1)

---

Teniendo en cuenta el siguiente diseño de tabla:

```
llamadas | prefijo | ciudad
---------+---------+-------
123456789|   123   | AAAA1
987546312|   987   | AAAA1
963852741|   963   | AAAA3
789456123|   789   | BBBBB
```

La consulta a realizar seria:

```
select COUNT(llamadas) Llamadas, ciudad Ciudad
from ddbb
group by ciudad
```

Y los datos resultantes serian estos:

```
Llamadas    Ciudad
   2        AAAA1
   1        AAAA3
   1        BBBBB
```

---

Answer (score 1):

Esto debería de funcionarte.

```
SELECT provincia, column1, LEFT(column1,3) AS prefijo, column2 COUNT(LEFT(column1 = 123))
FROM DDBB.table
Where prefijo between 000 and 1000
```

En cambio si lo que necesitas son valores específicos.

```
SELECT column1, LEFT(column1,3) AS prefijo, column2 COUNT(LEFT(column1 = 123))
FROM DDBB.table
Where prefijo in('123','657','897')
```

Si lo que quieres es agrupar por provincias necesitarás algo tipo:

```
SELECT column1, LEFT(column1,3) AS prefijo, column2 COUNT(LEFT(column1 = 123))
FROM DDBB.table
Where prefijo in('123','657','897')
Group by provincia
```

Obviamente, tienes que especificar las tablas correctas.